# I want to CheckMark selected rows in a UITableView based on contents of a UITextView

Tags: uitableview, uitextview, ios7.1

I have a UITextView populated with data from a UITableView (*tvServices*); when the user taps on a row in the UITableView, I move the contents of that cell to the UITextView, after which the contents of the UITextView are stored in a CoreData store.

When the user selects a record for updating, I move the contents of the stored UITextView back into the UITextView.  When the user taps on the UITextView, I display the entire UITableView as a UIPopover, with the contents of the UITextView marked with a checkmark (AccessoryCheck) in the UITableView.

Unfortunately, this is not working the way I designed it... nothing gets checked.  Here is my code ( this is a **proof of concept** - where I check every row in the UITableView to make sure it can be done).  *globalServicesArray* is the data source for the UITableView cells:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sharedServicesArray.globalServicesArray.count; i++) {
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tvServices cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

I hope this makes sense; if there is a better way of doing this, I'm open for suggestions... otherwise what am I doing wrong?

Comment: No it does not make sense, each iteration you create a cell `UITableViewCell *cell` and do nothing with it. you need to put some logic in `cellAtIndexPath`

Comment: I don't *create a cell*... the cell is already there in UITableView... I'm just altering the properties... and the app does display the contents of the UITableView, and it's correct with the exception of the AccessoryCheckmark.

Comment: where is this code running, I mean in which method

Comment: It's running in a method called *showServicesPopup*... what I have now noticed is that *path* is valid, but it doesn't return a cell from *cellForRowAtIndexPath*.... what would be the cause of that?

Comment: [like I said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144491/i-want-to-checkmark-selected-rows-in-a-uitableview-based-on-contents-of-a-uitext?noredirect=1#comment35390644_23144491) you dont do anything with that cell. You should have a condition in cellforrowatindexpath to check if it should have the check mark and return that. The loop you have here is kinda pointless

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only one cell can be edited, can you try this. Store the index path in a class level iVar/Property, say. selectedIndex and reload the cell

```
//To hold the index paths
NSMutableArray *reloadArray = [NSMutableArray array];
if (self.selectedIndex)
{
    //if already selected deselect
    [reloadArray addObject:self.selectedIndex];
}
for (int i = 0; i < sharedServicesArray.globalServicesArray.count; i++) {
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    [reloadArray addObject:path];
}
[tvServices reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:reloadArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

In cell for row at index path check for the index path and set accessory checked if matches the index

```
if (self.selectedIndex &&
    self.selectedIndex.row == indexPath.row &&
    self.selectedIndex.section == indexPath.section)
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```